# Can I play a game from Steam on different operating systems?

Tags: steam

Suppose if I buy some game like Middle Earth Shadow of Mordor on Steam. Can I play the game on both Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 9):

First, not all the games that are on Steam are available for Windows, Linux and Mac, so you need to carefully read the Steam page of the game to be sure.

But if it's a game compatible with both OSes like Middle Earth : Shadow of Mordor, then you can buy it once, and as long as you use the same Steam account on both Windows and Linux, your Steam Library will be the same, so you will be able to install and play the game on both OSes.

Comment: I think you wanted to stay "not all the games that are on Steam are available on both Linux and Windows". The way you put it, no game is available on both platforms

Comment: @ian_itor thanks for that, and thanks Timmy Jim for the edit. I try to make it clear but I still have some difficulties with English it seems. But yes that's what I wanted to say.

Comment: Shadow of War isn't even released.

Comment: Some games also save state in Steam Cloud, so you can use any computer to continue your game.